# What causes NG0303 error when using ngIf in a custom Angular library?

Tags: angular, angular-library, angular-module

Angular custom library: main.ts:6 NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container'

Hi everyone,

I have a problem with a component I'm getting from a custom library I've built (hosted as an Artifact on DevOps).
I have no problem downloading it and most components are working fine but I have a problem with th NavBarComponent.

Here's the html
`<lib-navigation [iconSource]="iconSource" ></lib-navigation>`

iconSource is an object that I loop through to set the menu and sub-menu in which there are different condition to display the menus and icons correctly.

Locally and on Storybook it works fine. But when I download it and set it in the html I get the error:

NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-container' (used in the 'NavigationComponent' component template).
If the 'ngIf' is an Angular control flow directive, please make sure that either the 'NgIf' directive or the 'CommonModule' is a part of an @NgModule where this component is declared.

My appModule looks like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { LibDesignSystemModule } from '@design-system/composants';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    LibDesignSystemModule
  ],
  providers: [    
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The designSystemModule is as below:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { LibDesignSystemComponent } from './lib-design-system.component';
import { ButtonPrimaryComponent } from './button/button-primary/button-primary.component';
import { NavigationComponent } from './navigation/navigation.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    LibDesignSystemComponent,
    ButtonPrimaryComponent,
    NavigationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
  ],
  exports: [
    LibDesignSystemComponent,
    ButtonPrimaryComponent,
    NavigationComponent
  ]
})
export class LibDesignSystemModule { }
```

The NavigationComponent is as below:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { NavigationComponent } from './navigation.component';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    MatIconModule,
    RouterModule
  ],
  exports:[
    
  ]
})
export class NavigationModule { }
```

And all the modules and components are in the public-api.ts

I think it is probably a problem with one of the imports of declarations and I've tried different ways of declaring the modules and components (in the library or the app using it) but nothing that worked so far. So I would gladly appreciate an exterior input on this issue

Thanks!

Comment: `ngIf` is a directive imported from the `@angular/common` module (`CommonModule`). You have imported `NavigationComponent`, but I don't see `NavigationComponent` declared in the `NavigationModule`. `declarations: []` --> `declarations: [NavigationComponent]`

Comment: Also, you pasted the NavigationModule instead of the component

Comment: I've made the changes and declared the component in the navigationComponent but I still get the error